# Entity Framework: missing saveChanges at first call, then it saves everytime

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, mvvm, savechanges

I know this is a weird problem, difficult to explain here. I'll try to do it, if I don't give you some infos you think it will be usefull, tell me and I'll add them.

So... I have my MVVM WPF app, when I start it and I do something with the data of the db (SQL Server), it doesn't save... but if I do again the same operations, it saves!! and so for all the successive attempts I can do...

I was thinking I do something in my code when I save the first time, so I have tried to do some useless mods in the database while the app is starting, calling the same method I call when I save using my GUI... but, as you can imagine since I'm writing here, it still doesn't save the first time (and only the first!).

How am I working?

For adding new data (or modify existing), I have a DbContext in a external dll. When I do add/mods data, I work in this context. In the end, I call the saveChanges method with a my function.

This is my partial class where I create the context:

```
public partial class Entities : DbContext
{
    public static Entities dbContext;

    public static Entities initContext() 
    {
        dbContext = new Entities(GetConnectionString("Model"));
        return dbContext;
    }
}
```

where with *Entities(GetConnectionString("Model"))* I'm creating a connection string and give it to the Entity Framework initialzer.

```
    public static string GetConnectionString(string model)
    {
        SqlConnectionStringBuilder(mdlImpostazioni.SetConnectionString());
        string cn = "server=" + mdlImpostazioni.p.dbServer;
        cn += ";database=" + mdlImpostazioni.p.dbName;
        cn += ";uid=" + mdlImpostazioni.p.dbUser;
        cn += ";pwd=" + mdlImpostazioni.p.dbPassword + ";";
        var providerSB = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(cn);
        var efConnection = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();
        efConnection.Provider = "System.Data.SqlClient";
        efConnection.ProviderConnectionString = providerSB.ConnectionString;
        efConnection.Metadata = @"res://*"; 
        return efConnection.ToString();
    }
```

I have done an override of the method saveChanges to do some audit jobs... it is very long, but I simply loop on the added and modded rows in this way:

```
    public override int SaveChanges()
    {

        bool badReturn = false;
        var addedAuditedEntities = Entities.dbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries()
            .Where(p => p.State == EntityState.Added)
            .Select(p => p.Entity);
        var modifiedAuditedEntities = Entities.dbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries()
          .Where(p => p.State == EntityState.Modified)
          .Select(p => p.Entity);
        var deletedAuditedEntities = Entities.dbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries()
            .Where(p => p.State == EntityState.Deleted)
            .Select(p => p.Entity);
            foreach (var added in addedAuditedEntities)
            {/*.......*/}
            foreach (var modified in modifiedAuditedEntities)
            {/*.......*/}
    }
```

but, pay attention..... *addedAuditedEntities* and *modifiedAuditedEntities*, when I do this first save of the app, are empty! So, there is a problem before this function... and, after the first, it works perfectly!!

I have copied this from the web to manage the saveChanges:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Wrapper for SaveChanges adding the Validation Messages to the generated exception
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context">The context.</param>
    public static int SaveChanges(DbContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            if (context.SaveChanges() == -1)
                return -1;
            return 1;
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (var failure in ex.EntityValidationErrors)
            {
                sb.AppendFormat("{0} failed validation\n", failure.Entry.Entity.GetType());
                foreach (var error in failure.ValidationErrors)
                {
                    sb.AppendFormat("- {0} : {1}", error.PropertyName, error.ErrorMessage);
                    sb.AppendLine();
                }
            }

            throw new DbEntityValidationException(
                "Entity Validation Failed - errors follow:\n" +
                sb.ToString(), ex
            ); // Add the original exception as the innerException

        }
    }
```

and I call it in this way:

```
int kk = utils.SaveChanges(Entities.dbContext);
if (kk > 0) 
    {
        if (attivazione.mdlImpostazioni.p.showSaveMessage)
            {
                dm.OkButton(ServiceContainer.GetService<DevExpress.Mvvm.IDialogService>("datiSalvati"), "Ok");
            }
    }
   SaveButtonEnabled = false;
```

I don't know if I can give other useful infos... tell me if I can do it.

UPDATE 1: [here my saveData function](http://www.heypasteit.com/clip/1W9B).. it is too long to write it in this post.

UPDATE 2: this is my App.Config.. as you can see there is no connection string here, but maybe it is useful

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
  </configSections>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0"/>
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer"/>
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>

  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="10.0.0.0" newVersion="11.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SqlServer.Diagnostics.STrace" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="10.0.0.0" newVersion="11.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlEnum" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="10.0.0.0" newVersion="11.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SqlServer.Dmf" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="10.0.0.0" newVersion="11.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlClrProvider" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="10.0.0.0" newVersion="11.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SmoMetadataProvider" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="10.0.0.0" newVersion="11.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="10.0.0.0" newVersion="11.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="10.0.0.0" newVersion="11.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlParser" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="10.0.0.0" newVersion="11.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SqlServer.ServiceBrokerEnum" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="10.0.0.0" newVersion="11.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SqlServer.Types" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="10.0.0.0" newVersion="11.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

UPDATE 3: question: if I update my entity framework? I'm working with the 6.0.0.. can upgrade to the last (6.1.3) help me? ---> **upgrade done, nothing changed!**

UPDATE 4: and [this is the method saveChanges](http://www.heypasteit.com/clip/1W9H).. I have done an override of it.

Comment: Can you post some code about "save operation"?

Comment: @RobertoConteRosito here, in this link I have put my saveData function.. can you see it?

http://www.heypasteit.com/clip/1W9B

Comment: if I update my entity framework? I'm working with the 6.0.0.. can upgrade to the last (6.1.3) help me?

Comment: where is `initContext()` first called probably after the first `SaveChanges()`?

Comment: also I wouldnt be using a `static` dbContext due to the way EF works ie building up a huge tracking graph of changes

Comment: yes, initContenxt it is called before the first saveChanges... and I know that make it static it is not the best way, but it was what I needed when I wrote it.. can this be the source of the issue?

Comment: I agree with @dellywheel. You should not use static objects for entity framework. Anyway I'm not able to see anything about entities management in the code you have posted.

Comment: @RobertoConteRosito ok, what can be useful for you? Further, if I make the context not static, can maybe solve this issue?

Comment: @PieroAlberto can you post code executed before "SaveChanges"? What and how you save your data (I think the previous code is related to the UI and not the methods invoked for data saving operations).

Comment: @RobertoConteRosito the code posted is what I do when I click the save button. SaveData is the binded commad stuff. I put a new link with all my saveChanges method (I have overridden it)  http://www.heypasteit.com/clip/1W9H